# Prevent the taskbar appearing on top of full-screen applications without disabling scaling on high DPI settings on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, fullscreen, high-dpi

My new laptop has a 13.3" monitor. Stupidly, its only supported widescreen resolution is 1920x1080, which by default makes everything really difficult to read. This has ultimately forced me to increase the default Windows font size to 150%.

I'm trying my hardest not to have to send the laptop back, but one thing which is pushing me towards that is the [issue with the taskbar appearing on top of full-screen applications](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/5dMYLChXeWk) when using high DPI settings.

There are three current solutions to this (on Windows 7, at least):

1. **Use the Basic theme instead of Aero.** Windows 8 has no Basic theme, nor Aero for that matter. The default theme is "Windows", and the only alternative is High Contrast.
2. **Reduce the font size.** Not an option due to what I've explained above.
3. **Change the program's compatibility settings to disable scaling on high DPI settings**. Again not really an option due to what I've explained above.

I could set my taskbar to automatically hide, but I'm Ideally I'm looking for a full on Windows 8 solution to this instead of just a workaround.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue whilst retaining my high DPI setting across all applications?